# Error inflating class com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView

Tags: android, facebook, fresco

I'm trying to use the fresco library. I used it before too and it was working, but now, for some reason I get:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.home.template/com.example.home.template.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
```

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">


<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyApplication:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    }
}
```

I have it in my manifest: `android:name=".MyApplication"`

The only problem that I'm having is with the draweeview. I can do all of the other stuff such as logging in and taking information.

Comment: are you using `fresco` library?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my case writing `Fresco.initialize(this);` before `setContentView(R.layout.myxml);` helped me.

**Update:**

you have `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);` instead of `Fresco.initialize(this)` in your `myapplication`

Comment: I tried that too and it isn't working, but now as you can see I have it in MyApplication as suggested in here https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/74

Comment: you have `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);`  instead of `Fresco.initialize(this)` in you myapplication

Comment: Yes, it's working. Should I keep both, or only one ?

Comment: just `Fresco.initialize(this)` is fine

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this problem in API 19 devices just because I was using drawable vector as placeholder here

```
fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/ic_phone"
```

After changing to PNG my problem was solved.

Dont forget to initialize it in your **App** as

```
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Fresco.initialize(this)
    }
}
```

as well as this line in manifest's application

```
android:name=".App"
```

Answer (score 2):

Today I had the same problem. However, I forgot to add the property `android:name=".MyApplication"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Application class write the following line:

```
Fresco.initialize(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you import the right Fresco library and if you do import other Fresco libraries, make sure the other libraries version number is the same with Fresco core library

Answer (score 0):

In my case writing `Fresco.initialize(this);`

before

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`